# Is TileMill opensource?

Tags: open-source-gis, tilemill

I was reading [this GIS.SE question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116316/any-reason-to-use-tilemill-if-mapbox-studio-is-meant-to-replace-it) about whether TileMill will be replaced by Mapbox Studio. I got worried about the future as a TileMill user, and the question suddenly came to me "isn't tilemill opensource?". Why can't we branch it if something goes wrong. To check, I went to their official website, and only found that [TileMill is]:

> Powered by open source 
>   TileMill is built on a suite of open source
>   libraries including Mapnik ...

Nothing is said about whether TileMill itself is open source. I went to the github site, and the license reads:

> Copyright (c), MapBox All rights reserved.
>
> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
>   modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
>   met:
>
> ```
> Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer. ...
> ```

The rest of the text looks pretty much open-source. What about the "MapBox All rights reserved." part? Does that conflict with the open-source spirit?

I am not familiar with the legal terms. But I don't see any familiar license terms like GPL, LGPL, apache or BSD.

My question is:

is TileMill open source or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TileMill is released under the BSD 3-clause license, an OSI approved license.

https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill/blob/master/LICENSE.md

So in answer to your question: Yes, TileMill is open source.

Mapbox Studio is released under similar terms:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio/blob/mb-pages/LICENSE.md

Some more information:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses
- http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
- http://opensource.org/osd

This answer from the Mapbox Studio FAQ may also be of interest:

> **Do I need a Mapbox account to use Mapbox Studio?**
>
> Yes, a Mapbox account is needed to access the default vector tile
>   sources included in Mapbox Studio. You can try out the features of
>   Mapbox Studio for free but to make use of all of the functionality you
>   must be on the Mapbox Standard plan.
>
> You are not locked into using Studio with Mapbox – you can export
>   vector tiles from any source project as a standard MBTiles file and
>   package any style project as a .tm2z package.